# Why the eval() is not working with array

Tags: javascript, eval

What's wrong with this code? Can anyone help out?

```
var read=new Array("i=10","j=20","k=i*j");
for(var i=0;i<read.length;i++)
{
    alert(eval(read[i]));
}
```

Expecting output:

```
alert three times with values 10,20,200.
```

But actual output:

```
But alert Once with value 10.
```

Comment: What do you think `eval()` does?

Comment: Define "not working". That's not a problem description.

Comment: first loop, `alert(eval(i=10))`, next step 10<3, condition fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the loop executes the first time, you are setting `i = 10`, with `eval`. So the loop breaks out immediately.

So, you might want to change the loop variable to something else, like this

```
var read = new Array("i=10","j=20","k=i*j");
for(var idx=0; idx < read.length; idx++)
{
    console.log(eval(read[idx]));
}
```

**Output**

```
10
20
200
```

**Note:** Please make sure that you read [this question and the answers to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), before using `eval` in your code.

Comment: var read=new Array("i=10","j=20","k=i*j")
    for(var index=0;i<read.length;i++)
    {
    alert(eval(read[index]));
    
    
     }

Comment: @user2807091 You have to change the condition and increment part as well. Check my answer.

Comment: @user2807091 simply remove `eval`, you can get the expected result. `alert(read[i]);`

Comment: @ling.s I would expect to get `10,20,200` but without eval i get `i=10,j=20,k=i*j`.

Comment: @Tibos If so, use the above answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var read=new Array("i=10","j=20","k=i*j");
for(var index=0;index<read.length;index++)
{
alert(eval(read[index]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

while the loop is executing, at the first execution of `i=10` the `i` variable is set to `10`; so loop will be terminated because of the condition `i<read.length` (here... `10<3`) remains false.

see the [`eval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) tutorial.